# Writing files to directories in a round robin pattern

Tags: python

I'm looking for a solution, from within Python, to write generated files in a round robin fashion to a set of target directories, such that the files are evenly distributed.

So if there were 5 target directories: D1, D2, D3, D4 and D5

and a constant stream of generated files (F1 .... Fn), the directories would be written to as follows:-

```
D1: F1, F6, F11 ... etc
D2: F2, F7, F12 ... etc
D3: F3, F8, F13 ... etc
D4: F4, F9, F14 ... etc
D5: F5, F10, F15 ... etc
```

Ideally there may be a python lib out there that allows this ...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.cycle` to get next directory for next file:

```
it = itertools.cycle( ['D1', 'D2', 'D3'] )

print next(it)
print next(it)
print next(it)
print next(it)
print next(it)
print next(it)
```

Result

```
D1
D2
D3
D1
D2
D3
```

---

```
it = itertools.cycle( ['D1', 'D2', 'D3'] )

for x in ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4' , 'F5', 'F6']:                      
    print x, 'write in', next(it)
```

Result

```
F1 write in D1
F2 write in D2
F3 write in D3
F4 write in D1
F5 write in D2
F6 write in D3
```

---

**EDIT:** as Kevin said

```
dirs = ['D1', 'D2', 'D3']
files = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4' , 'F5', 'F6']

for f,d in zip(files, itertools.cycle(dirs)):
   print f, 'write in', d
```

Result

```
F1 write in D1
F2 write in D2
F3 write in D3
F4 write in D1
F5 write in D2
F6 write in D3
```

Comment: I've never heard of itertools, but I'm huge fan of Haskell. What a cool library.

Comment: `cycle` seems like a good idea. What if you did `for filename, directory in zip(filenames, itertools.cycle(directories)):`? Then you wouldn't have to manually do `next`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a way to reference the appropriate directory for the current file. Since you have to index two non equal length lists, zip is not really appropriate here (which is a pity), but you can just achieve it like so:

```
files = ...
directories = ...

for i in range(len(files)):
    write_file(files[i], directories[i % len(directories)])
```

You can improve this using the `cycle` recommendation from furas, which allows zip:

```
from itertools import cycle

for f, d in zip(files, cycle(directories)):
    write_file(f, d)
```